# Eloquent: Get all rows where column value(x) exists in more than one row (SQL DB)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6, eloquent-relationship

I want to perform the following raw SQL query in Laravel's Eloquent:

`SELECT distinct user_id FROM order_payment WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM order_payment where payment_status = 'paid' GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);`

here I am using `where in` with property `user_id` such that all rows in the same table(`order_payment`) having `payment_status=paid` and grouped by property `user_id` having `count > 1` are selected and then finally we select `distinct user_ids` from the given set of user ids.

The overall objective of this query is to get all the rows where required column value(`user_id's in this case`) > 1...

Ex:

```
we have 3 rows > A, B, C
row A has user_id = 1;
row B has user_id = 1;
row C has user_id = 2;

result should have [user_id: 1] as the count becomes greater than 1
```

The above raw query work for me, but now that i am writing a api, I was wondering how this can be replicated in Eloquent.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the eloquent way for this query could be done using the `groupBy` and `havingRaw` methods

we first select the columns which we need to aggregate

`OrderPayment::select('user_id', \DB::raw('COUNT(user_id) as payment_made))`

then we groupBy the arribute we need - `groupBy('user_id')`, Note that the property we group by has to be in the select statement or this wont work.

Now the final clause where we see if there are multiple row having the same `user_id`, we use > `havingRaw('COUNT(user_id) > ?', [1])`

Now the overall eloquent query looks like this

```
OrderPayment::select('user_id', \DB::raw('COUNT(user_id) as payment_made))
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(user_id) > ?', [1])
    ->get();
```

Note that in the select clause we are passing the DB raw statement which passes as a string to the query builder and hence one should be careful with SQL injections.